# Error uploading proguard file to a Google Play Console

Tags: android, android-proguard

For those who faced `Invalid file content. Make sure you upload a symbol file.` trying to upload a `proguard-rules.pro(.txt or .cfg)` file.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Google Play Console wants us to upload `mapping.txt` file, which as mentioned 
[here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html#keep-code) is typically generated to `<module-name>/build/outputs/mapping/release/`